# Read characters with scanf("%c, &ch);

Tags: c++, arrays, char, scanf

I must enter characters with white spaces between them. For example, + / 8 7 - 9 '\n' (when I press Enter)
Then I write them in an array of characters and in it have something like this: +/89-9.

How can I skip these white spaces?

I tried to write something, but it doesn't work:

```
char *arr = new char[1000];
char ch;
scanf("%c", &ch);
int i = 0;
arr[0] = ch;
cout << arr[0];
while (ch != '\n') 
{
    //scanf("%c", &ch);
    scanf("%*[ ]%c", &ch);
    cout << (arr[i++] = ch);

}

arr[i++] = '\n';
```

Comment: Mixing C and C++ is a no no, use one functions or the other.

Comment: In the very first iteration of the loop, the variable `i` is still zero until *after* you do `arr[i++] = ch`. That means you overwrite the first character you read before the loop.

Comment: My code goes into endless loop, and I can't correct it, even I make variable change how you said.

Answer (score 0):

You were fairly close

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

From the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf):

> whitespace characters: any single whitespace character in the format
>   string consumes all available consecutive whitespace characters from
>   the input (determined as if by calling isspace in a loop). Note that
>   there is no difference between `"\n"`, `" "`, `"\t\t"`, or other whitespace
>   in the format string.

if you want to skip whitespace characters other than `\n` and keep reading one-by one (needs `#include <cctype>`):

```
while (ch != '\n') {
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    if(!isspace(ch)) {
        cout << (arr[i++] = ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: My code goes into endless loop, and I can't correct it

Comment: @fghjkl4083 That's because `scanf(" %c", &ch)` will never read `'\n'` into `ch`, since you told it to skip it.

Comment: How can I change that? I have no idea.

Comment: I can't change input string according to the task

Comment: I made something like this:

while (ch != '\n') 
 {
  
  
  scanf("%c", &ch);
  if (ch == ' ') continue;
  cout << (arr[i++] = ch);
  
 }

Comment: @fghjkl4083 added a second example

Comment: That'll work, provided your input doesn't have `\t` or anything other you could consider whitespace